# Forms authentication with URL fragments

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a single page application with ASP.NET MVC and Forms Authentication, so I'm heavily using URL fragment values(#). I'm aware that the server does not have access to fragments in the URL. I'm looking for the best/simplest solution to my scenario.

If the user is not authenticated and paste the URL http://example.com/account/#123 in the browser, they will be redirected http:example.com/signin?ReturnUrl=/account#123. Good so far.

But after they sign in, they are then redirected to http://example.com/account. The fragment value is lost.

How do I best design my application so the fragment is retained after signing in?

Comment: FYI, those are called url fragments, not hash values... hash values are the result of hash functions, and when you say things like "forms authentication" and use the word hash, the assumption is that you're talking about password hashing, which you obviously aren't.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Comment: Why are you using fragments for account numbering?  You should be using querystring parameters..

Comment: Thanks Erik. Updated my question. I used account ID just as an example. In general, I want to retain any fragment values after signing in.